# Why it is Undefined? How can i solve it?

Tags: json, asynchronous, ionic3

when i am trying to get this     console.log(this.empresas[0]); it says it is undefined, but empresas is loaded in the function.

```
empresas: any;

constructor(...) {
this.getEmpresas();
console.log(this.empresas[0]);
}

getEmpresas(){
this.empresas = [];
this.http.get("http://url").subscribe( data => {
this.empresas = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
}, err =>{
console.log(err);
});
}
```

Comment: your question is not so clear.

Comment: I just call a function and load the variable empresas. But, when i try to access it it says undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Because just by calling `getEmprass()`, the value of `this.emprass` will not get updated. `getEmprass()` will immediately return without updating it. **Later on**, when the http request is completed, `this.emprass` gets updated, but that is **after** the time you printed its value.

Many things happen in Javascript asynchronously. Observables and subscribe function is one of them: its content gets executed asynchronously in the future (similar to callbacks).

You may wanna change your code to this:

```
constructor(...) {
    this.getEmpresas();
    console.log('hey, getEmpresas() finished!');
}

getEmpresas(){
    this.empresas = [];
    this.http.get("http://url").subscribe( data => {
    this.empresas = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
    console.log(this.empresas[0]);//---------------------------> Print it here
}, err =>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

}

If you want to wait in constructor function until the http request is finished, you should use an [async function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/) .